# ¿Cómo agrupar un DataFrame por número de semana?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un archivo en formato CSV que contiene una columna con fechas desde el 1.º de enero de 2019 a la fecha.

Cada renglón puede tener varias veces la misma fecha.

Deseo agrupar los datos por número de semana, sin embargo por razones particulares la semana no inicia el lunes sino el jueves y termina el miércoles.

El objetivo es que a partir de la fecha de cada renglón, se cree una columna llamada semana en la cual asigne un número que corresponde a la semana.

Para el año 2019 el primero de enero es martes, por lo tanto este sería el día 6 y el 2 de enero sería el día 7 de la semana 1.

A partir del jueves 3 hasta el miercoles 9 en la columna semana se debe escribir el número 2 y así sucesivamente.

lo que he hecho es descomponer la fecha en varias columnas

```
fecha    year    month    day      dia        dia_mb

2019-01-01    2019    01    01     martes       6
2019-01-02    2019    01    02     miercoles    7
2019-01-03    2019    01    03     jueves       1
```

A partir de estos datos ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para crear la nueva columna semana en el DataFrame, considerando que cada vez que la fecha vaya aumentando y el dato en la columa dia_mb sea 1 se incremente el número de semana?.

[datos reales](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GhrPX8wlRl_BaenGFS8nNlevg8J_Iszd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, el valor que busca, llamémosle `my_weeknumber` ¿no sería igual al número de semana "normal" que te da `datetime.week` más 1 si `datetime.weekday>=3`? (es decir, es el jueves o más).

No estoy del todo seguro de haber entendido bien tu problema, pero de ser como yo digo, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv")
df.fecha = pd.to_datetime(df.fecha)
df["my_weekday"] = df.fecha.dt.week + (df.fecha.dt.weekday>=3)
```

Y ahora ya podrías agrupar por la columna `my_weekday`, por ejemplo:

```
for semana, datos in df.groupby("my_weeknumber"):
  inicio = datos.iloc[0].fecha
  fin = datos.iloc[-1].fecha
  print("La semana {} tiene {} elementos, que van de {} ({}) a {} ({})".format(
         semana, len(datos), inicio.date(), inicio.day_name(), fin.date(), fin.day_name()))
```

Lo que produce, con tus datos:

```
La semana 1 tiene 1 elementos, que van de 2019-01-01 (Tuesday) a 2019-01-01 (Tuesday)
La semana 2 tiene 44 elementos, que van de 2019-01-03 (Thursday) a 2019-01-09 (Wednesday)
La semana 3 tiene 52 elementos, que van de 2019-01-10 (Thursday) a 2019-01-16 (Wednesday)
La semana 4 tiene 48 elementos, que van de 2019-01-17 (Thursday) a 2019-01-23 (Wednesday)
La semana 5 tiene 33 elementos, que van de 2019-01-24 (Thursday) a 2019-01-30 (Wednesday)
La semana 6 tiene 35 elementos, que van de 2019-01-31 (Thursday) a 2019-02-06 (Wednesday)
La semana 7 tiene 40 elementos, que van de 2019-02-07 (Thursday) a 2019-02-13 (Wednesday)
La semana 8 tiene 36 elementos, que van de 2019-02-14 (Thursday) a 2019-02-20 (Wednesday)
La semana 9 tiene 35 elementos, que van de 2019-02-21 (Thursday) a 2019-02-27 (Wednesday)
La semana 10 tiene 31 elementos, que van de 2019-02-28 (Thursday) a 2019-03-06 (Wednesday)
La semana 11 tiene 36 elementos, que van de 2019-03-07 (Thursday) a 2019-03-13 (Wednesday)
La semana 12 tiene 39 elementos, que van de 2019-03-14 (Thursday) a 2019-03-20 (Wednesday)
La semana 13 tiene 35 elementos, que van de 2019-03-21 (Thursday) a 2019-03-27 (Wednesday)
La semana 14 tiene 37 elementos, que van de 2019-03-28 (Thursday) a 2019-04-03 (Wednesday)
La semana 15 tiene 34 elementos, que van de 2019-04-04 (Thursday) a 2019-04-07 (Sunday)
La semana 16 tiene 26 elementos, que van de 2019-04-11 (Thursday) a 2019-04-17 (Wednesday)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es una forma muy sencilla de hacerlo, ya lo probé y funciona, ahora solo resta agrupar mis datos con los criterios que requiero. Saludos

Comment: Trate de agrupar los datos con el ciclo for como sugieres pero me aparece el siguiente error. AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'day_name'

Comment: @AlejandroGomez Debes de tener una versión un poco antigua de Pandas. Cambia `day_name()`  por `weekday_name` (sin los paréntesis, no es una función)

Comment: Gracias lo voy a intentar

Answer (score 1):

Una forma muy simple de conseguirlo es usando `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` para agrupar semanalmente, pero especificando que el miércoles es el límite superior. Primero vamos a crear un ejemplo simplificado de tu csv:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


# Esto es solo para emular un fichero csv
data = StringIO(
'''fecha
2019-01-01
2019-01-03
2019-01-03
2019-01-04
2019-01-05
2019-01-06
2019-01-08
2019-01-09
2019-01-10
2019-01-11
2019-01-15
2019-01-16
2019-01-17
2019-01-18
2019-01-19
2019-01-19
2019-01-20
2019-01-21
2019-01-22
2019-01-22
2019-01-30
2019-02-01
2019-02-03
2019-02-06
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=["fecha"])
```

> La columna fecha debe estar perfectamente parseada, siendo de tipo `datetime64`

Esto nos genera un csv con una columna de fechas similar a la de tu fichero:

```
>>> df

        fecha
0  2019-01-01
1  2019-01-03
2  2019-01-03
3  2019-01-04
4  2019-01-05
5  2019-01-06
6  2019-01-08
7  2019-01-09
8  2019-01-10
9  2019-01-11
10 2019-01-15
11 2019-01-16
12 2019-01-17
13 2019-01-18
14 2019-01-19
15 2019-01-19
16 2019-01-20
17 2019-01-21
18 2019-01-22
19 2019-01-22
20 2019-01-30
21 2019-02-01
22 2019-02-03
23 2019-02-06
```

Ahora solo hay que agrupar por fecha:

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='fecha', freq='W-WED')
df["week"] = df.groupby(grouper).grouper.label_info + 1
```

> **Importante:** `grouper.label_info` está disponible solo a a partir de pandas 0.21.x, para versiones anteriores se puede usar:
>
> ```
> df["week"] = df.groupby(grouper).grouper.group_info[0] + 1
> ```

Lo que nos genera:

```
>>> df
        fecha  week
0  2019-01-01     1
1  2019-01-03     2
2  2019-01-03     2
3  2019-01-04     2
4  2019-01-05     2
5  2019-01-06     2
6  2019-01-08     2
7  2019-01-09     2
8  2019-01-10     3
9  2019-01-11     3
10 2019-01-15     3
11 2019-01-16     3
12 2019-01-17     4
13 2019-01-18     4
14 2019-01-19     4
15 2019-01-19     4
16 2019-01-20     4
17 2019-01-21     4
18 2019-01-22     4
19 2019-01-22     4
20 2019-01-30     5
21 2019-02-01     6
22 2019-02-03     6
23 2019-02-06     6
```

Para crear la columna con la identificación de cada grupo nos valemos del método [`pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy.grouper.label_info`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e4da9b07d500add644257b9fa317a668cf5e332/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1549) que asocia una etiqueta que identifica el grupo al que pertenece cada fila . Extrañamente, me temo que no está muy documentado.

> **Nota:** Probado con Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: ¡Tremenda buena noticia verte por aquí otra vez, FJSevilla! Me alegra mucho que vuelvas a estar presente en la comunidad.

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias por tu respuesta. Intenté utilizar pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy.grouper.label_info como sugeriste, pero me aparece el siguiente error AttributeError: 'BinGrouper' object has no attribute 'label_info', supongo que es la version de Pandas. intente actualizarlo pero anaconda me dice que no tengo permisos para actualizar paquetes.

Comment: @AlejandroGomez si, se debe a que tienes desactualizado pandas. Para solucionar el problema de permisos haría falta conocer más cosas (sistema operativo, dónde está instalada, etc). Si no es mucha molestia prueba con `df["week"] = df.groupby(grouper).grouper.group_info[0] + 1` y comenta si funciona.

Comment: @Alejandro lo he probado en pandas 0.20 dónde no existe efectivamente el método `label_info` (solo existe en pandas >= 0.21.x). Cambiándolo por la línea que comento antes funciona sin problemas, he editado la respuesta añadiendo esta observación, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, en cuanto lo pruebe comento. Saludos